# Parsing xml (encoding utf-16) in Elixir using sweet_xml

Tags: xml, elixir, utf-16

I have a utf-16 encoded xml that I want to parse. I'm using `sweet_xml`. The xml is received through the hook and changing encoding in xml is not an option. 
When I put `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` on the top of xml, everything works as expected but if I put `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>` (both tested from Postman) I'm getting `{:error, :not_utf16be}`. I'm not sure is it due to the library I'm using and I should look for another one or the problem is in xml?

Comment: Why do you put anything on top of the file you _are to parse_ in the first place?

Comment: I'm not putting anything. File is received through the hook and it has ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>``` on the top.

Comment: Share please the XML content you receive. Looks like it either misses [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) or the encoding is not actually _UTF16_.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share it cause there are some sensitive informations from our client. I'm not sure if online xml validators are relevant (I've tried couple of them) and all of them marked xml as valid.

Comment: Well, you are asking about “I have something I would not show you, please tell me why it does not work.” My best wild guess would be: _try to prepend `BOM` to the input before processing it_.

Comment: What happens if you try `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16le">`?